# 空文字とnullの使い分け

Tags: sql, firebase, データ構造

ユーザ情報を持つデータ構造を作成しています。
このユーザは、名前、住所を持ちます。

ユーザは、名前は必須ですが住所は任意です。
この場合データ構造としては、住所に何も入力がない場合はnullの方がいいのでしょうか？
それとも空文字で入力した方がいいのでしょうか？

ご教授宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考: [MySQLのvarchar データ型の初期値で Null と空文字をどのように使い分けるべきか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66361/3060)

Answer (score 1):

現場のシステムでは住所は４カラム程度に分割保持し、全てを連結した文字列を住所としてあつかっている場面によく遭遇します。
この時注意しないといけないのは利用しているRDBMSや連結方法に依存しますが、１カラムでもNULLの場合は連結後は全てNULLになってしまうケースがある事です。
この点留意して設計してください。（期待する回答にはなっていないと思いますが少しでも参考になればと、、）

Answer (score 1):

ケースバイケースですが、一つの考え方として

そのフィールドに、NULLを設定する必要がありますか？

この回答がNoであれば、そのフィールドはNot NULL制約を付けるべきです。
当然（少なくとも明示的に）NULLを設定することはありません。

住所にNULLを設定する要件はあまりないと思われます。
未設定と設定済みだがあえて空欄の場合を区別したいときとか、まあなくはないかもしれませんが。

あとDBMSによってはNULLと空文字列をきちんと区別できないようなやつもあるのでご注意を